# C++ Small char to hex function?

Tags: c++, hex, md5, valueconverter

I'm trying to find a very lightweight way to either hex a char or md5 one with two examples below.

```
char example[0x34];
char example_final[0x200];
sprintf(example, "%s", "4E964DCA5996E48827F62A4B7CCDF045");
```

For an example using two PHP functions below.

MD5:

```
sprintf(example_final, "%s", md5(example));
output: 149999b5b26e1fdeeb059dbe0b36c3cb
```

HEX:

```
sprintf(example_final, "%s", bin2hex(example));
output: 3445393634444341353939364534383832374636324134423743434446303435
```

Which ever is the most lightweight way to do it. I was thinking some big array of char to it's hex value than making a loop foreach char, but unsure.

Comment: An array of `char` to it's "hex" value won't be big: it will have 256 entries. When you do that, note that `char` may be signed and you'd better index the array as `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)`. BTW, where is your attempt to code the functionality...?

Comment: No because I'm not writing that array, lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of `bin2hex` would look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::string bin2hex(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string res;
    const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for(auto sc : input)
    {
        unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(sc);
        res += hex[c >> 4];
        res += hex[c & 0xf];
    }

    return res;
}


int main()
{
    std::string example = "A string";

    std::cout << "bin2hex of " << example << " gives " << bin2hex(example) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What in the world is "for(auto sc : input)"
I also don't know anything about standard cOut and try to avoid uses of strings because this is an xbox360 app.

Comment: `for(auto sc : input)` is a way to say "iterate over input, giving me the value in sc" - `for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) { char sc = input[i];` would be the same thing. You did mark this as C++, so I assumed using `std::string` would be fine - after all it's been in the C++ standard since the first standard in 1998, and in general is no less efficient than doing your own string handling. But if `res` is a (passed in?) `char array`, you'd do something like `int i = 0;` before the loop, `res[i*2] = hex[c >> 4]; res[i*2+1] = hex[c & 15];` and then `res[i*2] = 0;` after the loop.